Connection on $U(1)$-bundle vs. 1-form
My original idea of a $\mathfrak{u}(1)$-valued connection $\omega$ is that it's simply a normal $1$-form. But in the middle of page 3 of https://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0511710 he says "a connection on
a $U(1)$ bundle can be locally identified with a $1$-form, but not globally". Is he correct? Why?
If we choose an identification $\iota :\mathfrak{u}(1)\to\mathbb{R}$, then doesn't composing $\Omega_p:=\iota\circ\omega_p$, in which $p$ is a point in the upper space of the bundle, identify $\omega$ as a $1$-form $\Omega$?
Is there anything wrong?

Globally, one can only say that the difference of any two connections is a Lie algebra valued one form.
